# Caution: SAS prep guide data merging question has errata

Tags: merge, sas, dataset, certificate

I'm preparing for the SAS programming base certificate, I'm preparing using the book **SAS prep guide base programming 5th edition**, I'm in the combining data section, as I arrived in the Quiz in the question 6 which is the following :

[image]

I run the program in SAS ( as we have all the datasets ) and the output is :

[image]

however in the Quizz answer keys the results is :

[image]

Could the book be possibly wrong ? I answered the same like the book before running the program on SAS !

Comment: clearly a typo in the book then. You can't merge ID 1129 with any Age, Height, Weight if it is not in Cert.Set1.

Comment: @Schilker thanks, that's what i thought so !

Comment: With most of these types of quizzes they want you to pick the best answer.  What were the other possible answers?  Perhaps they were wrong in a much worse way than including one extra observation because of a typo in the way the inputs were displayed.

Comment: Did you check the errata/error page to see if it was noted as an error?

Comment: https://support.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/support/en/books/errata-base-certified.pdf Not sure if this is for version 5 thouh.

Comment: @Reeza i've found it in the errata pdf they've corrected it many thanks :)

Comment: Put a link to it and the correct answer and then mark the question solved.